# Update className using react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I have a span which has a className . The span has two state, one is like

```
<span  key={uuid()} ref = {colorRef} className = 'singleWord'>{word}</span>
```

and the other is like

```
<span  key={uuid()} ref = {colorRef} className = 'singleWord redword'>{word}</span>
```

Now what I want is to check the className value like className.classList.contain("oneClass') which we do in vanilla js but I need in react hook(may be with ref hook) and also add className and remove className . also is it possible to check the length of className .for example 'singleword redword' should give length 2.
So overall I need -

1. add or remove classes
2. check length
3. check if class contains or not
   I need to check them in react hook
   could anybody suggest how to do ??
   Thanks in advance

Comment: why not interpolate ?? ```className={`one-class ${condition ? 'another' : ''}`}```

Comment: I need to know is there any way of doing those stuff with useref or any kind of hook ? Rather traditional way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `colorRef = useRef()` hook, then you can obtain the target node by calling `colorRef.current` and proceed with vanilla js methods like
`colorRef.current.classList.contain("oneClass')` and so on.

Comment: colorRef.current.classList.contain("oneClass') gives me this error     Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contain')    i just console logged

Comment: You get this error because your code executes before the node mounts(inital render). At that time colorRef.current will be undefined. So you should execute the code inside an if condition `if(colorRef.current){ ...}` or using optional chaining like `colorRef?.current?.classList.contain('oneClass')`

Answer (score 1):

You can store in state an array of classes and use that to get all the information you need plus it gives an easy way to toggle any class in a set of classes.

basically this `handleClasses` function takes a class argument and then checks whether that class is already in your state. If it is, it removes it, if it's not, it add it to the state. Then in your span you join all the classes in the array in state to make a single string of classes.

Also you get the number of classes applied to your element very easily by doing `classes.length`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const [classes, setClasses] = useState(['singleWord']);

  const numberOfClasses = classes.length;

  const handleClasses = (c) => {
    setClasses(classes.includes(c)
      ? classes.filter((cls) => cls !== c)
      : [...classes, c]
    )
  }

  return (
    <span
      onClick={() => handleClasses(passClassToToggleHere)}
      className={classes.join(' ')}
    >
      text
    </span>
  )
};
```